# Getting project.build.property from maven in Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins

So this problem is vexing me and I decided to ask a question because no answer out there was able to help, the problem is happening SPECIFICALLY to project.build.directory.

I have a Jenkins pipeline, and I need to build this string to deploy my artifact

```
@${project.build.directory}\${project.artifactId}_${project.version}.car
```

I am using the following to get some information from the pom.xml

```
script {
         pom = readMavenPom file: 'pom.xml'
        deployVersion = pom.properties.'deploy.version'}
```

So doing both

```
${deployVersion}  and ${pom.version}
```

works perfectly, so there's no reason for ${pom.build.directory} not to work, but it doesn't. Nevertheless I decided to work around it and expose that property via the pom's properties, since I know the property works inside the pom, so I did, in my pom

```
<properties>
    <build.dir>${project.build.directory}</build.dir>
</properties>
```

And that don't work either, after assigning pom.properties.'build.dir' to buildDir I get ${project.build.directory} as a literal

```
@${buildDir}\${pom.artifactId}_${pom.version}.car
```

I have no idea why this is happening or how to fix. Any ideas?

**EDIT**: The below was answered in the comments, either escape with another slash `(\\`) or use a forward slash (didn't test this one though)

Even more weird, the \ disapears and it don't convert pom.artifactId (which will convert properly if I call it without the build directory)

Comment: Regarding the \, you have to escape it in order to make it part of the string `"@${buildDir}\\${pom.artifactId}_${pom.version}.car"`

Comment: Oh yeah, on the other parts that there are slashed, they are forward slashes, I thought was something related to escaping, I guess it just got caught with the weirdness of the rest :P